# Sitecore Log File Repeated Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have a sitecore 7.2 site and it is upgraded from 6.6, Any ideas what cause the following error to be appears many times in log file:

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 2015:07:14 10:03:48 ERROR Exception occurred in retryer scope :
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Retryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.Sql.SqlAutomationProvider.GetDueStates(AutomationStatesDataTable dataTable, Int32 maxEntries)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.AutomationWorker.GetDueStates(AutomationStatesDataTable dataTable)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.AutomationWorker.Process()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.AutomationWorker.<Wakeup>b__4(Object state)
   at Sitecore.Threading.ManagedThreadPool.ProcessQueuedItems()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Check you analytics connection string - try to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio using credentials from this connection strings

Comment: Initially the analytic connection string is incorrect I will correct it and monitor to see if the error will not appear in log file. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you see is thrown when the `Analytics` database connection string is incorrect.

Try to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio using credentials from this connection strings.

It is displayed multiple times because of Retryer which tries to re-execute the query after failing (see [Jason Home](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531602/jason-horne) answer for more detailed explanation of retryer).

Answer (score 5):

The reason you see the same error multiple times is because of the retryer which will retry failed database requests a number of times equal to that set in the number of tries param.

Below is the retryer section taken from web.config v7.2:

```
<!-- RETRYER
         When enabled, the Retryer resends failed database requests a specified number of times.
         For example, this is useful if you configure a Sitecore instance to support hot failover for database calls.
         Default value: disabled="true"
    -->
    <retryer disabled="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Retryer, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <param desc="Number of tries">6</param>
      <param desc="Interval between tries">00:00:00.500</param>
      <param desc="Log each exception (should be used for debug only)">true</param>
    </retryer>
```

Comment: Initially the analytic connection string is incorrect I will correct it and monitor to see if the error will not appear in log file. Thnks